# www folder empty in myApp ionic project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

i Cannot found any of css, img, and other folders in www folder after creating a basic ionic project.
i have used the command ionic start myApp blank.

### Im Using :

node -v

### v6.11.3

ionic -v
3.9.2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. How do you expect us to help you with this?

Comment: The folder will be empty until you serve or build app once.

Answer (score 3):

Thats because the contents of the `www` folder are created when you build your project using `ionic cordova build <platform>` or `ionic serve`.

Comment: and what is the solution !

Comment: run `ionic serve`

Comment: even if with that ionic serve .. still can't see any css, img, lib and js folders.

Comment: i just got new folders .. assets and build !!

Comment: There will never be one of those folder inside the `<project-root>/www` folder, the code you create in the `src` folder is bundled using webpack and goes into the `www/build` folder. If you want to use images in your project you put them in the `src/assets/img` folder and they go into the `www/assets/img` folder when you build your project.

Comment: anyway Thanks David for your response .. still have problem

Comment: Noo i have to modify in [app.js] .. so i need the js folder that i dont have

Comment: Ionic uses typescript, you do not have to modify any .js file. You shold probably start with the tutorial project: `ionic start myTutorial tutorial`